# React native build failed: The development server returned response error code 500

Tags: android, node.js, react-native

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPPfR.png)

Browser's console Error:

> Bundling `index.android.js`  [development, non-minified, hmr disabled]  99.3% (1074/1078), failed.
>   Error: Uncaught error in the transformer worker: /home/manish/donut/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/transformer.js
>       at _transform.then.catch.error (/home/manish/donut/node_modules/metro-bundler/src/JSTransformer/index.js:172:31)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have run the npm server. From your project root folder

Open terminal cd project root and run the following command

**npm start**

And if you are using command to compile and run the app on device or simulator, then make sure you have run the

react-native run-android or run-ios 
 command from different terminal, to make sure you have not closed terminal which you run npm start.

And see whether server started successfully

This can happen if import is not proper. Example if I try to import something like this below

```
import renderIf from './renderIf';
```

and there is renderIf file present in my project.

So all these types of issues will get printed in npm server logs. See the logs and fix it accordingly.

Comment: Done that too, but there was no effect.

Comment: Is the server running after you have compiled the app?

Comment: yes the server is running, but the app is not working

Comment: Could you post some code,  if server is up and running then it might be due to some other errors

Comment: Maybe do an npm-install?

Comment: I updated my answer, pls check. I encounter the similar issue, when my import was wrong. But issue was clearly printed in my npm server log.

Comment: When i build the app using 'react-native run-android' it shows error and then i run react-native start, it get stuck and after some time it shows error as "Uncaught error in the transformer worker: node_modules/metro-bundler/src/transformer.js" and also in "node_modules/metro-bundler/src/JSTransformer/index.js:172:31"

Comment: I tried deleting the node_modules folder and reinstalling it using npm install. But then also it didn't worked